# Django using LIKE in an inappropriate way?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to do the following

```
from core.models import *
q1 = MessageRecipient.objects.filter(message__subject__icontains="Enfim")
```

Producing the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE `message`.`subject` LIKE %Enfim%
```

[image]

Look at the like statement.

Django is not using quote.
Am I missing something here? I bet I am. Cause this is a common used feature. Somebody would realize if it was a bug.
What's happening?

Comment: You can copy and paste from the junky Windwos terminal. Right click on the title bar and get properties, then set it to quick edit mode, I think it's called? Can't remember, I haven't used it for a while.  Then when you highlight with the mouse and press Enter, it is copied to the clipboard.

Comment: I know that, thanks. Just did that way so people won't think i'm messing up with the test.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `__str__()` method of the `Query` object at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py, you'll see the following warning in the docstring:

> Parameter values won't necessarily be quoted correctly, since that is
>   done by the database interface at execution time.

Don't worry about it, it's not important, seems to be the message! This is not a bug, as such, you just need to think about what you're using `.query` for. It's fine for a spot of debugging, or to [pickle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets), if you want to recreate a query set with up to date results at a later date. It's not something you can pass directly to your database.